# Reverse a map matlab converting array to string keys

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary, matrix

I have a map defined as:

```
diagonal = eye(4);
v = {diagonal(1,:), diagonal(2,:), diagonal(3,:), diagonal(4,:)}
k = {1, 3, 7, 8}
class_labels = containers.Map(k, v)
```

Now I need a reverse map, but Matlab does not allow key to be array and hence I need to convert each array to string.

So my class_labels map look like:

```
1 => [0 0 0 1]
3 => [0 0 1 0]
7 => [0 1 0 0]
8 => [1 0 0 0]
```

I need something like:

```
0001  => 1
0010  => 3
0100  => 7
1000  => 8
```

Comment: Are the arrays always going to only contain zeros and ones?  And how many entries are you planning on having?

Comment: @RoryYorke Yes. Always having 0's and 1's. the rows in the arrays will always be equal to the size of the map. Basically each 1 is to represent class label.

Comment: I think your forward map is wrong.  Shouldn't `1 -> [1 0 0 0]`, `3 -> [0 1 0 0]`, etc.?  I'm going purely with what you have coded.

Comment: @rayryeng is there a difference between `=>` and `->`? I am new to matlab so what I have coded is correct. Please ignore the representation.

Comment: No, that's just to illustrate the relationships between them. `->` or `=>` is not valid MATLAB syntax.... well 1 gets mapped to the first row of the identity matrix, which is `[1 0 0 0]` is it not?  In any case, I think I have an answer for you

Comment: Two questions: Are the keys in the forward map guaranteed to be numerical?  Are the values in the forward map guaranteed to be numerical arrays?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes and Yes.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam - One more... are the numerical arrays in the forward map only consisting of `0/1` ?  Could you have a value of... say... `[12 34 56 7890]`? What do you do in this case?

Comment: @rayryeng only 0 and 1's. To be even more specific, only one `1` and rest everything 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keys` and `values` methods associated with the `containers.Map` class to extract the keys and values, then apply a string conversion to the values by concatenating all of the bits together.... then simply construct another `containers.Map`.  What you'll do is use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to iterate through each cell element of the values cell array and apply a function such that it converts the sequence of numbers in the array into a concatenated string.

Let's assume for the moment that you don't have access to the keys and values already defined by you and let's say we only have access to the `containers.Map` itself.  You want to invert the dictionary, and so:

```
%// Your code
diagonal = eye(4);
v = {diagonal(1,:), diagonal(2,:), diagonal(3,:), diagonal(4,:)};
k = {1, 3, 7, 8};
class_labels = containers.Map(k, v);

%// New - Get the keys and labels
kr = keys(class_labels);
vr = values(class_labels);

%// Concatenate all of the bits of the values into a string
vr = cellfun(@(x) char(48+x), vr, 'uni', 0);

%// Create new dictionary
new_labels = containers.Map(vr, kr);
```

This line here is probably the most confusing: `vr = cellfun(@(x) char(48+x), vr, 'uni', 0);`.  `cellfun` iterates over all cells in a cell array and applies a function to each cell.  This function is the first input into `cellfun`.  I declared an anonymous function where it takes in the contents of a cell in the cell array... so this would be the array of values, then adds 48 to each of the digits.  This gives us an array of `48/49` instead of `0/1`.  Once we do this, we cast this array to `char` so that the digits are represented as their ASCII or string equivalents.  The ASCII code for `0/1` is `48/49`.  By using `char` on this modified array, what is produced is a string that concatenates all of these characters together.  The second input is the cell array we're working on, and the third and fourth parameters tell you that the output of `cellfun` is not a numeric vector but another cell array of values.  `'uni'` is short for `'UniformOutput`', and this is set to `0/false` because the output of this function is not a numeric vector, but a cell array of vectors.  Each cell would be the string created by concatenating all of the numbers in the numeric array together.

If we show the keys and values, we get:

```
>> keys(new_labels)

ans = 

    '0001'    '0010'    '0100'    '1000'

>> values(new_labels)

ans = 

    [8]    [7]    [3]    [1]
```

You can see that each string key maps to the right inverse value.

Comment: It worked, but can you explain how concatenation is happening?

Comment: Also could you look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919933/specified-key-type-does-not-match-the-type-expected-for-this-container-matlab I am having problems accessing the map because of data type conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to map your arrays to strings or doubles, and possibly
back again.  From the constraints you've given, you can use `find` to
"encode" the vectors; decoding is not achievable in a one-liner (I
don't think), but something like

```
function idx2vec(i,n)
% I - index to set to 1
% N - length of vector
  v = zeros([1,n]);
  v(i) = 1;
end
```

You could use this technique to get a single argument key->array
converter:

```
function f= fidx2vec(n)
  function v=idx2vec(i)
    v = zeros([1,n]);
    v(i) = 1;
  end
  f = @idx2vec;
end
```

For general arrays, you could use `mat2str` (array to key) and `eval`
(key to array) instead.

For readability, I wrapped find in vec2idx:

```
function i=vec2idx(v)
  i = find(v);
end
```

and added this to your code:

```
diagonal = eye(4);
v = {diagonal(1,:), diagonal(2,:), diagonal(3,:), diagonal(4,:)};
k = {1, 3, 7, 8};
class_labels = containers.Map(k, v);

rk = cellfun(@vec2idx, v, 'uniformoutput', false);

reverse_map = containers.Map(rk, k);

for iv = 1:length(v)
  fprintf('%s -> %g\n',mat2str(v{iv}),reverse_map(vec2idx(v{iv})));
end
```

to produce:

```
[1 0 0 0] -> 1
[0 1 0 0] -> 3
[0 0 1 0] -> 7
[0 0 0 1] -> 8
```

A final comment: this solution maps your arrays to the positive
integers.  Matlab has a perfectly good container mapping positive
integers to doubles, called arrays!  If your keys are dense (i.e., all
or most values from 1:n will be used), I'd just use an array instead
of a containers.Map.  You could use `nan` to mark non-existent
entries.  If your keys are sparse, that is your arrays are length
(say) 1000, but only 50 possibilities are used, containers.Map is a
reasonable option.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse map can be done using [**logical indexing**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
 allValues = [1 3 7 8];
 value = allValues(logical(key));
```

For example,

```
 >> allValues = [1 3 7 8];
 >> key = [0; 0; 1; 0];
 >> value = allValues(logical(key))
 value =
      7
```

If the key happens to contain several ones, the corresponding values are returned as a vector

```
 >> key = [1; 0; 1; 0];
 >> value = allValues(logical(key))
 value =
      1     7
```