# Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, cell

I have a `cell_array` for which `29136x1 cell` value shows in the workspace pallet. I also have a map  `new_labels` with `4x1 Map` in workspace pallet. Printing `new_label` on prompt gives

```
new_labels = 

  Map with properties:

        Count: 4
      KeyType: char
    ValueType: double
```

Each entry in the cell_array is the key in the map, but the problem is there a type mismatch as `keyType` in map is char and entries of `cell_array` are of type `cell`.

Because of this I cannot access the map and hence something like the following:

```
arrayfun(@(x) new_labels(x), cell_array, 'un',0);
```

gives error `Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.`

I tried converting to char type using `char_cell_array = char(cell_array)` but that converts the array to be of size `29136x4` which means every entry is just one `char` and not really a string.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the iterative way, you have to use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).  `arrayfun` operates on numeric arrays.  Because `cell_array` is a cell array, you need to use `cellfun` instead of `arrayfun` as `cellfun` will iterate over cell arrays instead.

However, what you're really after is specifying more than one key into the dictionary to get the associated values.  Don't use `arrayfun/cellfun` for that.  There is a dedicated MATLAB function designed to take in multiple keys.  Use the `values` method for that which is built-in to the `containers.Map` interface:

```
out = values(new_labels, cell_array);
```

By just using `values(new_labels)`, this retrieves all of the values in the dictionary.  If you want to retrieve **specific** values based on input keys, supply a second input parameter that is a cell array which contains all of the keys you want to access in the `containers.Map` object.  Because you already have this cell array, you simply use this as the second input into `values`.

## Running Example

```
>> A = containers.Map({1,2,3,4}, {'a','b','c','d'})

A = 

  Map with properties:

        Count: 4
      KeyType: double
    ValueType: char

>> cell_array = {1,2,2,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,2};
>> out = values(A, cell_array)

out = 

    'a'    'b'    'b'    'c'    'c'    'd'    'a'    'a'    'a'    'b'    'b'
```